# Bing Azure Web Search Api: how to avoid query spam from malicious robots?

Tags: bots, spam, bing-api

I'm working on a metasearch site using Bing Azure Web Search Api.
Starting from 2 days (after a month of no problems) I'm facing the problem of avoid to recieve spam searches from malicious bots.
They aren't flooding the site, they query in slow mode (1 or 2 query/sec). IP are all differents, they aren't in any public black list and obviously I cannot use captha for a search interface!

How to avoid this problem?

Answer (score 1):

A common trick is to set up `robots.txt` with an off-limits area, then sprinkle some invisible links into this bot trap.  Human visitors will not discover that it's there, well-behaved bot's won't go there.  Maybe you want to give the occasional visitor the benefit of the doubt, but repeat offenders can be blacklisted and rejected on the TCP level (or better yet, refer them to http://projecthoneypot.org/)